# Add bootstrap.inc to file to programatically save nodes

Tags: 7

In Drupal 6 I would add these two lines to my code so that I could programatically import fields without having to create a module for it

```
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

However, trying to do this in D7, I am getting all types of errors from defined constants not being defined.  What is the proper way to do this in d7?

I have my script ready, and I do not want to spend another several hours writing code just so this can fit nicely into drupal as a module.  Thoughts? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on a MAC, and apparently there is an issue with how mysql sockets are handled.

If you are on a Mac and having issues with PDO exceptions as well as REMOTE_ADDR not found, do this:

1. Execute the following commands:

```bash
    sudo mkdir /var/mysql
    sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

1. Put this at the top of your PHP script:

   ```
   $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'example.org';
   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1';

   chdir('/root/drupal/folder/'); // Change this to your root Drupal address for local.
   define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
   require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
   drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Drupal 7 uses the `DRUPAL_ROOT` constant that is set to the Drupal root directory path. If you look at the code of the index.php file, you will notice the following code.

```
/**
 * Root directory of Drupal installation.
 */
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
menu_execute_active_handler();
```

The constant is also used from Drupal functions, such as [`module_load_include()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7).

```
  if (function_exists('drupal_get_path')) {
    $file = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . drupal_get_path('module', $module) . "/$name.$type";
    if (is_file($file)) {
      require_once $file;
      return $file;
    }
  }
```

If you have to write, for any reason, a function similar to `module_load_include()` you should use `DRUPAL_ROOT` to get the Drupal root directory.

Supposing that in your case Drupal is not in the current directory, you can use the following code.

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', 'the directory containing Drupal');

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```